# Linq - filter a child list<object> without affecting Parent row count

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a scenario where I need to filter on a child `list<object>` **ResponseIssues** that is being included with the parent **Question** which is also a `list<object>`.  For this example, I have 10 questions I'm pulling back from a table that I will always need to pull back whether or not there are ResponseIssues.

There appears to be a couple of problems with my query.  The first problem is that the number of **Questions** goes from 10 to 1 since I currently only have one question associated with **ResponseIssues**.  I need all questions to come back.

The second problem is that when I look closer at the **ResponseIssues** child `list<object>`.  While I'm seeing records that are associated with the question, it's not filtering out rows by *SuveryPeriod* and *RespondentByQuarterId*.  I'm expecting one row and I'm getting three rows where two of the rows where from a previous period.  The same issue happens for the Responses child list.

Here's my current code below.  Any ideas on how to restructure the query where it factors in the above issues and returns a Questions object and not something anonymous?

```
var question = await _dbContext.Questions
                 .Include(x => x.Responses)
                 .Include(x => x.ResponseIssues)
                 .Include(x => x.SurveySection)
                 .Include(x => x.Survey)
                 .Where(x => x.SurveyId == surveyId &&
                             x.Responses.Any(r => r.SiteUserId == siteUserId &&
                                                  r.SurveyPeriodId == surveyPeriodId &&
                                                  r.RespondentByQuarterId == 2
                                            ) &&
                                             x.ResponseIssues.Any(ri => ri.SurveyPeriodId == surveyPeriodId && 
                                                                        ri.RespondentByQuarterId == 2
                                           ))
                 .OrderBy(x => x.Position)
                 .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do the above by breaking it out into three separate queries rather than just one.  I still would be curious to know if someone in the community has a way to do it as one query though.

Anyway, here's my code below.  I'm able to update the Questions Parent with the correct number of rows for both Responses and ResponseIssues along with returning all of the questions.

```
var question = await _dbContext.Questions
                                .Include(x => x.SurveySection)
                                .Include(x => x.Survey)
                                .Where(x => x.SurveyId == surveyId)
                                .OrderBy(x => x.Position)
                                                  .ToListAsync();

var responses = await _dbContext.Responses
                                .Where(x => x.SiteUserId == siteUserId &&
                                            x.SurveyPeriodId == surveyPeriodId)
                                .ToListAsync();

var responseIssues = await _dbContext.ResponseIssues
                                .Where(x => x.SurveyPeriodId == surveyPeriodId &&
                                            x.SiteUserId == siteUserId)
                                .ToListAsync();


foreach (var item in question)
{
    var foundResponse = responses.Where(x => x.QuestionId == item.Id).ToList();
    var foundResponseIssue = responseIssues.Where(x => x.QuestionId == item.Id).ToList();

    if (foundResponse != null)
    {
        item.Responses = foundResponse;
    }

    if (foundResponseIssue != null)
    {
        item.ResponseIssues = foundResponseIssue;
    }
}
```